# Travis build failing on "The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but..."

Tags: angular, karma-runner, travis-ci, google-chrome-headless, angular-test

My Angular app tests are passing locally, however they are failing on [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) with the following error:

> The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured
>   correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You
>   need to make sure that /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox is owned by
>   root and has mode 4755.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by editing my `karma.conf.js` file and adding the following object to my `customLaunchers`:

```
ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
  base: 'ChromeHeadless',
  flags: ['--no-sandbox']
}
```

so my `karma.conf.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // other parameters...
    browsers                : [
      'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'
       // other browsers (if any)
    ],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
      // other browsers (if any)
    },
  });
};
```

then I run my test with `--browser=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox`